# Get text label of parent option group

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html:

```
<select id="categoryg">
<optgroup label="Main" value="binding">
<optgroup label="Sub" value="binding">
                        <option value="46">Test</option>
                        <option value="47">Test2</option>
                        <option value="48">Test3</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Whenever I change the selection I want to get the label text of the parent option group "Main".

At the moment my code just gets the label text of the sub parent option group "Sub".

This is my code ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3tw49khs/15/)):

```
$('select').change(function () {

   var opt = $(this).find(':selected');
   var sel = opt.text();
   var og = opt.closest('optgroup').attr('label');
   
   console.log(og) // Sub, should get Main;

});
```

Comment: Optgroup isn't allowed to be nested within itself. When the HTML is processed by your browser, the first optgroup is closed with no content and the second will contain the options below it. So closest should return sub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. The "closest" optgroup is the parent of the selected option. That's what it means. Also, nesting optgroups (it looks like that is what you are trying to do) is problematic at best.